# Opensearch DSL - Find records with field not equals each other

Tags: dsl, querydsl, elasticsearch-dsl, opensearch

Is it possible to query records that has two field not equals each others?

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM <index> WHERE FIELD1!=FIELD2;
```

Comment: Any chance you figured this out? Looking for the same thing and banging my head against the wall.